# One space is added in the beginning of input string

Tags: python-3.x, printing, user-input, text-indent

I am trying to print a line by taking the user input.
But there is an empty space before the user input is printed:

Code:

```
UserInput = input('Enter a string: ')
print("\nEntered string is:\n", UserInput)
```

Output:

```
Enter a string: I need this, but not this

Entered string is:
 I need this, but not this
```

Ideally the output should have been:
Enter a string: I need this, but not this

```
Entered string is:
I need this, but not this
```

Please can someone let me know??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is causing an extra space before the user input string. Replace the comma in the print statement with `+` sign.

```
UserInput = input('Enter a string: ')
print("\nEntered string is:\n" + UserInput)
```

Output:

```
Enter a string: I need this, but not this

Entered string is:
I need this, but not this
```